# Angular ci tests has different outcome locally than DevOps

Tags: angular, unit-testing, npm, azure-devops, karma-jasmine

I have a problem with my pipeline. I know that my current Karma tests are broken, but I am experiencing an **inconsistency** between running the tests locally and on DevOps pipelines

> karma.conf.ci.js

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary', 'cobertura'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit'],
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: 'test-output'
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

Command is `npm run test-ci` (`"test-ci": "ng test --code-coverage --karmaConfig=karma.conf.ci.js"`)

After fixing some tests and excluding others, I get this command to run with exit code 0 locally from WebStorm

On WebStorm, it reports a lot of warnings

```
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.
07 04 2021 11:55:27.299:INFO [Chrome Headless 89.0.4389.114 (Windows 10)]: Connected on socket a_CSFlZVK9QoDFJIAAAB with id 48577154
LOG: 'Wanted to read 'xxxxxx_authWellKnownEndPoints' but nothing was found'
Chrome Headless 89.0.4389.114 (Windows 10): Executed 0 of 18 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
LOG: 'Wanted to read 'xxxxxx_authWellKnownEndPoints' but nothing was found'
Chrome Headless 89.0.4389.114 (Windows 10): Executed 0 of 18 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
LOG: 'Did not find matching route for https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxx/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'
Chrome Headless 89.0.4389.114 (Windows 10): Executed 0 of 18 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
LOG: 'Wanted to read 'xxxxxx_authWellKnownEndPoints' but nothing was found'
Chrome Headless 89.0.4389.114 (Windows 10): Executed 5 of 18 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.133 secs)
LOG: 'Wanted to read 'xxxxxx_authWellKnownEndPoints' but nothing was found'
Chrome Headless 89.0.4389.114 (Windows 10): Executed 5 of 18 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.133 secs)

Chrome Headless 89.0.4389.114 (Windows 10): Executed 7 of 18 (skipped 1) SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.336 secs)
Chrome Headless 89.0.4389.114 (Windows 10): Executed 15 of 18 (skipped 3) SUCCESS (0.609 secs / 0.452 secs)
TOTAL: 15 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 15 SUCCESS

Process finished with exit code 0
```

On Azure, results are different

> azure-pipelines.yml

```
  - task: Npm@1
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      customCommand: 'run test-ci'
    displayName: 'Execute Unit Tests'
```

Here is an interesting part

```
Chrome Headless 89.0.4389.90 (Linux x86_64) FilterFormBuilderService should be created FAILED
    HttpErrorResponse: Http failure response for https://localhost:5001/api/v1/secure/xxxxxxx: 0 Unknown Error
Chrome Headless 89.0.4389.90 (Linux x86_64): Executed 14 of 18 (1 FAILED) (skipped 3) (0 secs / 0.787 secs)
Chrome Headless 89.0.4389.90 (Linux x86_64) FilterFormBuilderService should be created FAILED
    HttpErrorResponse: Http failure response for https://localhost:5001/api/v1/secure/xxxxxxx: 0 Unknown Error
Chrome Headless 89.0.4389.90 (Linux x86_64): Executed 15 of 18 (1 FAILED) (skipped 3) (0 secs / 0.854 secs)
Chrome Headless 89.0.4389.90 (Linux x86_64): Executed 15 of 18 (1 FAILED) (skipped 3) (1.406 secs / 0.854 secs)


- Generating browser application bundles...
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! xxxxxx@0.0.0 test-ci: `ng test --code-coverage --karmaConfig=karma.conf.ci.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the xxxxxx@0.0.0 test-ci script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

This is twicely interesting

1. `FilterFormBuilderService` spec does **NOT** depend (triple-checked) on any Http component
2. Locally, the API server at port :5001 is shut down

### Question

<strike>Why do tests fail on CI but succeed locally?</strike>

Why does my testing script fail **with error 1** for a simple http unreachable host error despite all individual trivial tests succeed? If a test depends on http, **that** test should be reported as failing so that the implementor can either fix or ignore the test.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your project depends on build environment. If you use [Microsoft-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software) in Azure pipeline, its environment is different from your local machine, thus you see different build result. You could [deploy self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install),  which give you more control to install dependent software needed for your builds and deployments. And then use it in pipeline so it will build your project by running on local machine.

BTW, you could set variable system.debug to true in pipeline to get [debug logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops), so you could view it to get detailed build information.

Comment: In fact, pipeline runs on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the culprit test **by exclusion**, after endless attemtps to run the pipeline.

I had a test where basically the component under test wants to perform some AJAX invocations because of a service dependency. Yes, it violates the **unit** principle of unit testing, but I was simply unable to locate that test and determine that it caused failure depending on the environment.

I am posting as an answer, but I am really confused because I haven't really solved my problem: understanding why tests fail with error code 1 along with the pipeline.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), it could help other community members who get the same issues and then share more feedback here, thanks.

Comment: I could, but I haven't understood my problem yet. I just worked it around 

Comment: Have you tried using self-hosted agents in pipeline? How about the result?